# Map height based on screen width with zoom level 0

Tags: java, android, google-maps, height

I'm trying to calculate and set programatically the height of google's map view, to be the exact height of the shown map content. I use zoom level 0 because I want to present the whole world.

The problem is, that I don't find how to get the actual height of the map's content given that the width is constraint to parent width (=device screen). I rather get the map cut from top+bottom or I get large padding on the top+bottom. See snapshots below.

I know that according to [google docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/views#zoom)  the width at zoom level 0 will be 256dp (256 * 2^N dp, where N is zoom level). However, I need the width to match device's screen size, and there is no documentation about the height ratio/dimensions.

Getting the measured dimensions is straight forward:

```
int width = mMapView.getMeasuredWidth();
int height = mMapView.getMeasuredHeight();
```

I can calculate the zoom level based on the screen width:

```
float zoom = (float) (Math.log(width / 256.0) / Math.log(2));
```

However, I again don't know what shall be the right height to show the whole world.

If I set android:layout_height="wrap_content", it only cares about the logo, so I get a squised map with ~138px which doesn't make any sense. This is my xml for the map view:

```
    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:liteMode="true"
        map:cameraZoom="0" />
```

Does anyone know how to calculate the height of the map's content based on screen width?

[image: google map with unneeded padding]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to find the real north and south edges of the Mercator projection, then somehow convert the distance between the 2 to some height value you can use in your map container. That might involve adjusting the container height after the map was shown (no idea how that works with Android).

Comment: @MrUpsidown I'm not sure it will solve the issue, it seems like google maps calculates the map's height based also on device's screen parameters, like dp.
Can you show the code that you think shall do the magic?

Comment: @DeadStar have you found any solution?

Comment: @mefahimrahman unfortunately no. Do you have any idea?